# Downloading code from Arduino mega

Tags: arduino-mega

A while ago I made a code for a drag timing system and uploaded it to my Arduino mega after that I broke my computer and got a new one and I don't have that code anymore. Does anyone know how to recover it from my Arduino?

Comment: this has been asked before

Comment: You can easily recover the binary (look up avrdude and the command your IDE uses to upload to the board), but you won't get your source code back from that.